# Is there a difference between this two ways of doing callbacks (jQuery)?

Tags: jquery, callback

I'm just starting to learn jQuery and I've seen this. I don't know if there is any difference or which one would be better.

```
myDiv.fadeOut('fast', function() {
    myDiv.removeClass('slide');
});
```

And

```
myDiv.fadeOut('fast').removeClass('slide');
```

Comment: first one removes the class when fadeout is completed. in second case, class is removed when fadeout is being processed.

Comment: The second one isn't using a callback. There you're just chaining methods.

Comment: The above two comments are both correct. There is also no 'correct' or 'better' method - they are both used in different situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback to `.fadeOut` call fires when fade out finishes. So this

```
myDiv.fadeOut('fast', function() {
    myDiv.removeClass('slide');
});
```

will remove the class at the end of animation while this:

```
myDiv.fadeOut('fast').removeClass('slide');
```

removes the class after `.fadeOut` is initialized, basically at the begining of the animation.

There is no answer to the question "which is better?" because these two are functionally different. That totally depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you, I did not realise because they *seem* to behave the same way in the thing I'm trying to do (having a slow-ish computer does not help either)

Comment: @Nemuri Yeah, it might seem to be the same because the animation is very fast. But they aren't.